# check whether data available in orm database

Tags: java, android, database, orm, sugarorm

Is it possible to add the data in to the sugarorm db by this method? I want to validate if the user is already in db, if yes then display "user available" else I want to insert the value in the database.Can some one help me with this validation?

private void postDataToSQLite() {

```
        User.find(User.class, "email = ? and password = ?", email, password);
```

Comment: Sugar ORM Providing save(), delete(), findById(....) for Basic CURD Operations. If you are using sugar ORM then you can use these functions but i think "create(name, email, password)" not a sugar ORM function. is it correct ? if it is correct i think you need to share the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Need to change the if condition. You are currently checking the user already exits or not. But issue is you trying compare two string using "==" this. But if you need to compare two string you have to use "equals"

Current Code

```
   if (user.getEmail() != textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim() || user.getPassword() != textInputEditTextPassword.getText().toString().trim()) {
```

New Code

```
if (!user.getEmail().equals(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim()) || !user.getPassword().equals(textInputEditTextPassword.getText().toString().trim()) ) {
```

Comment: sorry its a mistake ,now i cant click my register function.could u please check where am making mistake.

Comment: noh errors .i was debugging .after i enter the registering details i cant press my register button.

Comment: D/SQL Log: SQLiteQuery: SELECT * FROM USER  ....in the log i can see this but i cant click register  button

Comment: I think this is not related to the question. So i think you need to ask another question.

Comment: basically what i am trying to check here is whether the register details i am entering is already there in db or not.i am using the validation there.but after i enter the details and if i click register button i cant click it.is there any wrong in ma implementation(logic)